# Integrate C library into gnatstudio

Tags: ada, gnat, visa

I have an Ada application which communicates on a GPIB bus.  I have the C file which call the VISA commands but I get undefined references for viOpenDefaultRM, viOpen, viWrite, and viRead.  I have the visa32.lib and visa64.lib but can't figure out how in reference these into my gnatstudio build.

Comment: Did you already try to add linker options `-lvisa32` or `-lvisa64` in the project settings? Or add `pragma Linker_Options (...)` in the spec file that imports the functions. [This](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Using-DLLs-with-GNAT.html) page in the GNAT manual provides guidance on how to use DLLs with GNAT.

Comment: This is obviously a linker-related issue, but you should also consider direct-interfacing with GPIB. IIRC, the VISA commands are particularly structured and you could likely implement it in Ada to provide yourself more correctness and maintainability, rather than having to deal with the mess of C-based interface/API.

Answer (score 2):

I only have the 2019 version of (what was then called) GPS.

In that, *Edit* > *Project Properties*, and then in the Properties dialog *Build* > *Switches* > *Ada Linker*; in the input line at the bottom enter `-Lwherever -lvisa32` or `-lvisa64` as required.

(The `-Lwherever` tells where to find visa32.lib)

Answer (score 0):

I added the line to Build > Switches > Ada Linker but it doesn't use the -L or the -l options.  I just added the directory where it is located: "../lib/visa64.lib"

Thanks for your help.